# Get first input from a Container on each Table row

Tags: jquery, html

I have this table:

```
<table id="fieldContainer">
<tr><td><input id="input1"></td><td><input id="input2"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input id="input3"></td><td><input id="input4"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input id="input5"></td><td><input id="input6"></td></tr>
</table>
```

How do I get only first input on each tr?

current code:

```
$('#fieldContainer :input').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

wanted input:
`input1`,`input3`,`input5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
$('#fieldContainer tr td:first-child input').each(function(){
     alert($(this).val());
});
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BAhEb/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:first` pseudo-selector:

```
$('#fieldContainer tr input:first')
```